# How to make Media Player Classic HC play audio as mono instead of stereo?

Tags: audio, media-player-classic, stereo, mono

I'm using Media Player Classic HC (MPC-HC) and I want to know how to make it play in mono sound output instead of stereo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Derived from the German version: Go to `View` >> `Options` >> `Internal Filter` >> `Audio-Switcher`. Check the following boxes:

- Enable built-in audio switcher filter (requires restart)
- Enable custom channel mapping

Mark all speakers on all channels (if you want to mix them up) or choose your dominant input channel. Don't forget to switch off normalization, which is set to 400% by default.

See screenshot below, just make sure all boxes checked in it are checked on yours.

[image]

Comment: Might have to check a box saying "Enable custom channel mapping"